# Trifecta DataPrep has an expired SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-dataprep, trifecta

I'm just following the basic documentation to call the DataPrep API:
https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/API-Workflow---Run-Job_145281449

I got the Access Token ready but seems like DataPrep API has a expired certificate

```
$ curl 'https://api.clouddataprep.com/v4/jobGroups/$ID' -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN'
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

You can check: https://whatsmychaincert.com/?api.clouddataprep.com

Currently it says:

> api.clouddataprep.com has a trusted chain containing an expired certificate. This chain will work with modern web browsers (they will use a chain to a different trusted root) but may fail with older clients, notably OpenSSL 1.0.x.

Answer (score 2):

could you please try again, the certificates are fixed and you shouldn't see this issue anymore.